# Science fiction novel/novellete I read in late 70s: power struggle in a society of immortals

Tags: story-identification, novel

The plot involves a power struggle in a society of immortals. The only things I remember for sure are they would shower in flames to burn off any wear and tear and would heal immediately and look youthful again. All of the homes or territories held by clans or something like that had deep, deep "ceremonial" wells that you discover the purpose of toward the end of the book. Anyone know the name of the work and the author?

Comment: The ceremonial bathing in flame reminds me of the (long lived) Giants in Stephen Donaldson's "The Land".  But the rest doesn't sound right.

Comment: Reminds me of the movie She, with Ursula Andress which was based on a novel of the same name

Comment: Do you remember any other details? What do the wells do? Is it sci-fi or more of a fantasy novel?